# What is ISP proxy?

Tags: isp, proxy

One of my customer requested to implement data center for server space rental service. He need to rent his server for data center and ISP proxies. I can setup as a data center. But i have no idea about ISP proxies.

- What is ISP proxy and what it is doing?
- What are the implementation Requirement of ISP proxies (like sneaker bot)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

ISP proxies are used by mass mailers, scammers and other ne'er-do-wells to appear to be residential users when sending out their data.  The idea is to make it harder for spam filters and blacklists to block them.

Do you really want them as a customer?

Comment: i don't think, it is illegal requirement because he told me that once a data center is complete we need to discuss with ISP to take ip pool. If it is a illegal requirement how can we talk to ISP?

Comment: I can't comment on whether it's illegal, and I wasn't suggesting it was.  I'm just asking (rhetorically perhaps)  whether you want those kinds of clients.

Comment: Some use ISP proxies for testing of availability and responsiveness, but yes, most users are malicious or at least borderline.